# Can assign integer value to char but can't assign integer variable to char

Tags: java, char, int

Why doesn't the following code compile

```
int n = 5;
char c = n;
```

but the following does compile

```
char c = 5;
```

Aren't I just assigning an integer value to char in both cases?

Comment: But this works, `char c = (char) 5;` Note that the range of int is much greater than that of char, and so assigning an int to a char is not guaranteed to be legit.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So it only comes down to the discrepancy between char- and int ranges?

Comment: My guess would be that char is a 16bit  but int is a 32 bit . So when assigning 5 to char it fits in 16 bits so it's cool but int clearly is to large. Reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Integer.MAX_VALUE is 7fffffff, while a char can go up to '\uFFFF'

Comment: @Victor2748 The question you referred is different. He is pointing other thing.

Comment: What part of the quote *Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:* isn't the answer to this?

Comment: Because the question is dealing with adding integer values to `char`, whereas this one is expressly dealing with conversions between `int` to `char`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `char` can be assigned to an `int` without a cast because that is a widening conversion. To do the reverse, an `int` to a `char` requires a cast because it is a narrowing conversion.

See also [JLS. Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html).

Answer (score 6):

His question is why his code does not compile, not how to do what he's trying to do.

The reason the line

`char c = n`

does not compile, is because the range of char (-2^15 to 2^15 - 1) is much smaller than the range of int (-2^31 to 2^31 - 1). The compiler sees you are trying to assign an int to a char, and stops you, because it realizes this.