# error: variable data might not have been initialized

Tags: java, debugging, compiler-errors

Im getting this error, however Im not entirely sure why, I did declare(line 6) and initialize(line 11) the variable, yet I still get the error. the code is as follows:

```
public static char ReadChar (String prompt, boolean gui) {
    // Enter (prompt, True) for gui popup, else enter prompt and false

    // set up data and objects
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char data;
    String dataGui, strData;


    // prompt for an input int value
    if (gui == true){

        dataGui = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
        data = dataGui.charAt(0);

    }

    else {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        strData = input.nextLine();

    }
    return data;

}
```

Comment: what if `if` statement is false then only else part is executed so data is not initialized

Comment: `char data;`  you need to initialize `data`. You can use `char data = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Assign data varible value. as `data` is assigned if gui is true but what if data is false. so either u hava to assign `in else` or `at a time of declaration`. as to avoid mistake you need assign local varible. Java doesnt forces to initialize instance variable and allows default value but for local variables its the developers call to assign the value.

```
 char data = 0;
```

Comment: well that was easy. thank you so much

Comment: I thought because it was a char i couldn't set it to 0 but it just compiled :D

Comment: @BekahMarie - Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446512/can-assign-integer-value-to-char-but-cant-assign-integer-variable-to-char) question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21317631/java-char-int-conversions?lq=1)

Comment: @BekahMarie you can initialize a `char` in `Java`  `char c=0`.Which will give you an empty value of character

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `char`.

```
char data = '\0';
```

or

```
char data = 0;
```