# Assigning an Integer literal to a char data type in Java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, integer, char

While learning Java, I came across the statement -

"You cannot assign an integer to a char data type directly without explicitly casting it"

I tried the below example :

```java
char ch = 65;
System.out.println(ch);
```

Output :
`A`

I did not perform any type casting and was able to assign an Integer to a char data type. This is contradicting to the above statement.

Also,

```java
int i = 65;
char ch = i;
System.out.println(ch);
```

Output :
`Error`

This rightly gives me an error and asks me to typecast it.

Why was I able to assign an integer to a char in the first case and not in the second case?

Comment: There is a difference between a variable and a literal. If we play around  with the above, we see that `char c = 65_535;` works, while `char c = 65_536;` fails. This also exlains why `int i = 65; char c = i` does not work: `i` could have a value `> 65_535`. Now one may try to `short s = 1; char c = s;`. This will also fails since `s` (and any other numeric primitive variable) may be negative.

Comment: If you can explain the same example using `short` instead of `char` will give the same*  results, you have your answer for this.  (* Except the `short` example would output `65` instead of `A`)

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of this:  [Can assign integer value to char but can't assign integer variable to char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446512/can-assign-integer-value-to-char-but-cant-assign-integer-variable-to-char)

Comment: That's not an assignment: that's an initialization.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Why was I able to assign an integer to a char in the first case and not in the second case?"*

The first example uses a *literal*, *65*, which appears to be handled slightly differently than the *variable*, *i*.
This is just a function of the *interpreter*.

The documentation for this would be in the *[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/index.html)*.

Comment: It is not a function of the interpreter. It is a question of initialziation *versus* assignment.